# Rails: seeding database data and date formats

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, data-migration

I'm trying to seed some data into a Rails 3 app that I'm developing, using the db/seed.rb file and the rake db:seed command.

The data I'm seeding involves a database table called Meeting that has three columns: string title, datetime startDate, datetime endDate. The datetimes I'm trying to insert are in "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm" format -- eg. "01/02/2003 13:23" = January 2, 2003 1:23 PM. However, the DateTime.parse() is consistently erroring out with an "invalid date" error -- as it tries to parse the dates in "dd/mm/yyyy" format.

From my Googling, I've been led to believe that when parsing DateTime objects the compiler looks at the string that's passed in and does some hasty pattern matching and then maps "mm/dd/yyyy" and "dd-mm-yyyy" accordingly per American/British(etc) standards based on whether a slash or a dash was used as a seperator. This doesn't seem to be the case, however, and I'm wondering why. And how to fix it.

This is how I'm seeding the Meetings -- the first one parses properly, the second one fails.

```
Meeting.create([
  {
    :title => "This meeting parses fine",
    :startDate => DateTime.parse("09/01/2009 17:00"),
    :endDate => DateTime.parse("09/01/2009 19:00")
  },
  {
    :title => "This meeting errors out",
    :startDate => DateTime.parse("09/14/2009 8:00")
    :endDate => DateTime.parse("09/14/2009 9:00")
  }])
```

Comment: try to add zero to hour `:startDate => DateTime.parse("09/14/2009 08:00")`

Comment: @fl00r no that didn't work; I added a seed for "09/01/2009 08:00" and that worked. It's the dates that are being difficult.

Comment: Try putting your dates in a more obvious format for the parser: `2009-09-01 8:00`

Comment: I'm seeding on the order of 700 dates; rewriting them is not an option. Frankly, my Googling indicates that mm/dd/yyyy _is_ an obvious format for the parser. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try `Date.strptime`

```
:startDate => DateTime.parse("09/14/2009 8:00") 
#=> 
:startDate => DateTime.strptime("09/14/2009 8:00", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

so

```
Meeting.create([
  {
    :title => "This meeting parses fine",
    :startDate => DateTime.strptime("09/01/2009 17:00", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"),
    :endDate => DateTime.strptime("09/01/2009 19:00", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
  },
  {
    :title => "This meeting errors out",
    :startDate => DateTime.strptime("09/14/2009 8:00", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
    :endDate => DateTime.strptime("09/14/2009 9:00", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
  }])
```

Answer (score 10):

Use `DateTime.new` instead. No worries about proper parsing then.

```
Meeting.create([
  {
    :title      => "This meeting parses fine",
    :startDate  => DateTime.new(2009,9,1,17),
    :endDate    => DateTime.new(2009,9,1,19)
  },
  {
    :title      => "This meeting errors out",
    :startDate  => DateTime.new(2009,9,14,8),
    :endDate    => DateTime.new(2009,9,14,9)
  }
])
```

Comment: Don't forget the comma in :startDate  => DateTime.new(2009,9,14,8),

Comment: Missing commas added. Thanks @Acrux.

Answer (score 2):

If the specifics of the entered time aren't important, you can totally skip formatting with:

```
Time.now.to_datetime
Time.now.to_datetime.end_of_day
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to seed Date data that makes sense is using Gem Faker:

Gem
https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker

Date
https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker/blob/main/doc/default/date.md